# Figure out what character is in a string in R

Tags: r, string, character-encoding

I am trying to figure out what the special characters are in a vector of strings that is causing me problems.

One particular example is a string that looks like it says "-coliform", the 1st entry in my vector.

But this cannot be what it actually says because I get the following:

```
>"-coliform" == vect[1]
[1] FALSE
```

So obviously "-" is not actually the correct symbol. This is causing problems because I need to remove all punctuation from the strings, but some of the punctuation characters aren't being recognized as punctuation.

**How do I figure out what character I am actually being shown, so that I can remove it?**

I'm not sure if it is an encoding problem. It seems that the character is in UTF-8 which I found by doing the following:

```
>weird_char <- substr(vect[1], 1, 1)
>encoding(weird_char)
[1] "UTF-8"
```

Edit: Adding the output given by something as per the request of another user.

```
>dput(vect[1])
"–coliform"
```

To clarify, there are other special characters which are also not being recognized as punctuation (though they appear to be). So replacing all instances of the dash will not fix the problem.

Comment: Could you show output of `dput(vect[1])`?

Comment: If you only want to retain alphanumeric characters you could try `x <- gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", x)`

Comment: @CPak Added that output. The problem is, even if I can figure out what that one character is, there are several thousand entries in the vector, many of which contain unusual characters. For example, I also just found several containing "‘’".

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman it did not solve my problem. If you read the main part of my question, it says “there are other special characters which are also not being recognized as punctuation (though they appear to be). So replacing all instances of the dash **will not** fix the problem.

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman there is already an example in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try to find out what the characters are, you can use the unicode package

```
library(unicode)
as.u_char_seq("–coliform", "")
[1] <U+0096,U+0063,U+006F,U+006C,U+0069,U+0066,U+006F,U+0072,U+006D>
```

`<U+0096>` looks like it translates to a control code for "Start of Protected Area"

If you have many unknown characters and want to retain just the alphanumeric ones, you can use

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", "–coliform")
[1] "coliform"
```

Or it there is a certain punctuation or other character that you do want to keep, you can add it in to the gsub statement with a pipe `|`

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:]|? ]", "", "–coliform?") #keep question mark
[1] "coliform?"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `gsub`

```
gsub('-', '', '-coliform')
```

even if you have more than one

```
gsub('-|\\^|\\%', '', '-co%li^form')
```

if you have a colmun

```
x = c('-co%li^form', '-total_coliform')
gsub('-|\\^|\\%|\\_', '', x)
```

list the characters in your `string` and separate them with `|\\`

Comment: This does not solve the problem by circumventing the issue, nor does it answer the question I asked. As per the body of my question, “there are other special characters which are also not being recognized as punctuation (though they appear to be). So replacing all instances of the dash **will not fix the problem**.”